# How to using source js in development mode via Grunt(and min.js in production mode)?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

Suppose there are `a.js` and `b.js` files.
In production environment, I must merge `a.js` and `b.js` into `lib.js`; but in development environment,I just direct reference to the source code in HTML.

That is, in development mode, I will using that HTML fragment:

```
<script src="a.js"></script>
<script src="b.js"></script>
```

And, In a production environment, I get the following code fragment:

```
<script src="lib.js"></script>
```

Looks like `grunt-contrib-uglify` seemingly does not offer this feature.
Any plugin of Grunt has good solution?
(I think it's also useful in `css`)

Comment: https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-bower-concat

Comment: @pc-shooter I want wirte a.js and b.js in HTML, when I want to release it, I just run grunt build to replace it to lib.js. Can `grunt-bower-concat` do it?

Comment: As far as i see in th docs, yes

Comment: @pc-shooter It just concat some js files to one js file. It don't care development or production. Using concated js file is not good for me.

Comment: @pc-shooter I want a tool to auto replace my script tag to one concated js file.

Comment: `grunt-usemin` is your friend, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21148042/concat-bower-components-with-grunt/21153927#21153927