# Grunt concat JS and rewrite links in HTML

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, minify

I m using Grunt for processing some task and I would like to concatenate multiple JS files to one file while building application.

Lets say I have some JS files:

```
js
├── plugin-1.js
├── plugin-2.js
└── plugin-3.js
```

And I would like to build assets to this file:

```
js
└── plugins.js
```

I can do this simply by running Grunt... BUT.

In some HTML templates I have link to these JS files:

```
<script src="js/plugin-1.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugin-2.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugin-3.js"></script>
```

And I would like Grunt to rewrite this to:

```
<script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
```

Are there some possibilities for this?

Comment: https://github.com/spatools/grunt-html-build

Comment: It looks like you are trying to avoid any build phase while developing. Please don't.

Comment: It isnt static html, but jgilich solution seems to be fine (github.com/spatools/grunt-html-build) Thanks. I m not trying to avoid build phase. I m just looking how to build properly:)

Comment: [grunt-usemin is your friend here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21148042/concat-bower-components-with-grunt/21153927#21153927)

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for a solution to this problem, too, and I found one: use the grunt module [`gunt-use-ref`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-useref).

It might help you although I finally decided that a static approach (with one minified file including all styles or js respectively) fits my needs better. Why? Because having individually concanated and minified files need to be loaded for every single page whereas a single file with all stuff included remains in the browser cache (check the [H5BP template's .htaccess](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/.htaccess) for example) and just needs to be downloaded once. So decide which usecase you are having: if you expect visitors to visit just one page go with the individual approach for a fast first page load, if you expect them to visit different pages go with the one-fits-all solution for a fast experience when visiting many pages.

From the docs: