# How do I automatically, with Grunt, reference the new (minified & concatenated) JavaScript files in HTML?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

My index.html page looks like this:

```
  <html>     
  <script src="js/file1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/file2.js"></script>
  <script src="js/file2.js"></script>
  </html>
```

Using `grunt` i was able to concat and minify the js files into one file at `prod/js/file.min.js`. I also have a new `index.html` page at `prod/index.html` that is minify.

The problem now is that this new `index.html` page still reference the old three javascript files and not the new single javascript file. How would I go about changing this in grunt?

final html file should be:

```
  <html>     
  <script src="js/file.min.js"></script>
  </html>
```

Comment: Copy your Gruntfile please.

Comment: Perhaps suits your needs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21148042/concat-bower-components-with-grunt/21153927#21153927

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use grunt-processhtml plugin to replace it

https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-processhtml